# rendering render partial path theme yii2

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

the stucture of my yii(2) application is like:

```
   ___Backend
   ___frontend______
  |             |__ controllers
  |             |       |__ SiteController.php
  |             |       |__ ... (other controllers goes here...)
  |             |__ models
  |             |__ views
  |             
  |       
  |       __ 
  |       
  |       :
  |
  |__ themes(my theme)
           |__CompanyProfile
                            |__Index.php
                            |__CSS
                            |__fonts
                            |__...
```

i rendered in yii 1 by using folloving code:
(yii 1)

```
public function actionPages($id){
    Yii::app()->theme = 'CompanyProfile';
    $this->renderPartial('CompanyProfile/views/layouts/Index',array(
        'model'=>PrCompany::model()->findByPk($id),
    ));
}`
```

But I coud not manage to renderPartial in yii2. How can i renderPartial it in yii 2

Answer (score -1):

try

```
public function actionPages($id){
    $this->renderPartial('@frontend/themes/CompanyProfile/views/layouts/Index',array(
        'model'=>PrCompany::model()->findByPk($id),
    ));
}`
```